# Equality of morphisms between objects in a category

Tags: category-theory

In the book "Category theory for programmers" the following exercise is given:

Generate a free category from a graph with one node and one (directed) edge (hint: this
edge can be composed with itself).

Considering the hint, I suppose the expected solution is that you add an identity arrow `I` to the node and then you add infinitely many arrows, each of which represents an arbitrarily long sequence of compositions of the edge that we started with.

Now my question is: If we denote the starting edge by `E`, then why is the composition of `E` with itself not equal to `E`, but the composition of `I` with it is equal to `E`? Is this just a definition thing? What sets apart `I` from `E`? After all, it can't be the source node and the target node, because then we would have `E = I` and we would be done without adding any edges.

More generally, if we interpret the set of nodes of a graph as objects in a category and the edges between them as morphisms, when are two sequences of edges considered equal?

Comment: I'm not that deep into category theory (thus just a comment, no answer), but from my intuitive understanding, in free "things" generated by a given set of objects, those generators will never be "special constants". Like the zero vector is never part of a basis of a vector space. In the same way I expect that the identity morphism, which is guaranteed to exist as a "special constant", will not be part of a freely generating set. I expect that your category will contain a morphism $f$ (the given edge) as well as all morphisms $f^n$, where $n\geq0$ and $f^0=\operatorname{id}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the composition of `I` with it is equal to `E`

This is required in the definition of a category: There must be an identity morphism for each object.

> why is the composition of `E` with itself not equal to `E`

This is what "free" means. Roughly, a "free" category means we want it to be a category but no extra conditions are imposed. $E\circ E\circ \cdots \circ E=E$ will be an extra condition, hence not free.

More generally, the free category generated by a directed graph has morphisms of the form of either $I_v$ (the identity morphism from vertex $v$ to itself) or $E_1\circ E_2 \circ \cdots \circ E_n$ where $E_i$'s are edges of the graph, and they can be connected. Note that here we are assuming none of $E_i$ is the identity morphism which is added as extra data just for the axioms of a category to hold. The compositions are defined in the obvious way. Two morphisms $E_1 \circ \cdots \circ E_m$ and $F_1\circ \cdots \circ F_n$ are equal iff $m=n$ and $E_i=F_i$.

It can be more abstractly defined through the universal property, roughly this means for any graph $G$ in a category $\mathcal C$, there is a unique functor from $F(G)$ to $\mathcal C$ that extends $G\hookrightarrow\mathcal C$. Intuitively, if there is any special relation that may not be satisfied by some category containing $G$, it will forbid the extension, hence $F(G)$ has no special relation other than being a category.